# Maintain 2 branches with similar code, but not identical

Tags: git, svn, version-control, bitbucket, git-merge

I have 2 environments and 2 branches, testing and production. The code on the testing branch (Angular) is 99% the same as the production branch, but there are a couple of differences in production which I need to maintain, such as removing the "sign up" and "create new" buttons while the live site is still in beta. But I 100% need these views in version control, and I need them on the testing branch / environment.

Is there a way to maintain 2 slightly different files even when I merge, without using .gitignore? Its like I need to .gitignore just a few lines of code!

My current method is to simply remember the changes, and re-do them every time I merge into the production branch, then undo the changes when I switch back to testing branch. Its getting a bit annoying though!

I could set an environment var to switch the lines of code of course, but its then trivial for anyone to see this in the (client side) code and use my hidden links and buttons.

My deployment process is as follows:

1. Commit changes to either branch in Atlassian (Bitbucket) SourceTree software.
2. Push changes
3. Push is picked up for
   automatic deployment via Codeship.com
4. Codeship deploys via
   Elastic Beanstalk or directly to S3

So environment variables and build scripts can run during the codeship or EBS phases.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What's your deployment environment and method?  Tell us more...

Comment: Why don't you suppress the "sign up" and "create new" button at runtime using a environment variable or something? It would not be visible in the client if you don't print the code containing the links/buttons.

Comment: Does the contents you want to remove from testing branch always immutable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is to isolate branch specific code in a small set of files and then switch between then in your production and dev branches using a setting in your config file (rather than an environment variable).

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was simple, and it shows me how to do it right, rather than what I was doing wrong; Branches for new features, only merged into the appropriate deployment branch + some client side config for cosmetic purposes :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to maintain 2 slightly different files even when I merge, without using .gitignore? Its like I need to .gitignore just a few lines of code!

You have an implied premise, that `.gitignore` would help you here.  It won't.  The *only* thing `.gitignore` does is keep untracked files untracked (by default).  It does not affect merges.

So let's remove that and address the correct question:

> Is there a way to maintain 2 slightly different files even when I merge

For all intents and purposes, no.  You could try, but there are much better solutions to the underlying problem.

What you'd have to do is, define one direction for merges, and then introduce the difference on the "target" side of the merge.  But then (1) you're open to the potential for unnecessary merge conflicts every time you merge the affected file, and (2) you're tying your own hands with a very restrictive rule on merging.

(To the last point: suppose you decided "always merge toward production".  That doesn't sound *too* different from the gitflow rule of "merge toward master"... but what about hotfixes?  Even an indirect merge from production to test would break this approach, so the process of creating a hotfix would be made far more complicated.)

A better solution is to use a single code base, but use environment-specific configuration to decide which behavior is expressed.  The configuration could be managed by your build process, or picked up directly from the environment at runtime.

Comment: +1 last paragraph.  That's why I asked for more information about the deployment environment and process.  If we had that information, it might be possible to provide more help.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll add a bit more info re my deployment process. Yes, I set variables and builds for the separate deployments. But I don;t see how that helps in this situation...